# C# Console.Write overload methods

Tags: c#, console

I know how this piece of code works, but the arguments of the Write method get me confused. I know that `Console.Write("{0}",n); prints n,` but what does `Console.Write("{0,3}",n);` do? Wouldn't `Console.Write("{0} ",n);` or
`Console.Write(n+" ");` do the same thing? Is it about the way that the values are separated?

```
 int n;
    n=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    while (n>=0)
    {
        Console.Write("{0,3}",n);
        n--;
    }
```

Comment: it's simply the count of characters it will print to the console ... if the value of n has less digits it will fill the rest with spaces...

Comment: `{0,3}`, 0 means first parameter of object[], 3 means right align of 3 characters.

Comment: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The `,3` in `Console.Write("{0,3}",n);` is an instruction to pad the value with spaces, to a minimum length of three.

Writing out the value `1` gives `"  1"`, writing out `12` gives `" 12"`, writing out `1234` gives `"1234"`.

It gives the same result as:

```
string s = n.ToString();
Console.Write(new String(' ', Math.Max(0, 3 - s.Length)) + s);
```

Comment: @IulianDutu: I don't know. The title for the downvote button says *"This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"*, but I don't think that either clearly applies. Perhaps some people thought that the question had some weaknesses in all aspects, and the sum would be enough for a downvote.

Comment: I searched it on google, i gave a bunch of details and it helps me